# Pass extra values along with urls to scrapy spider

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I've a list of tuples in the form (id,url)
I need to crawl a product from a list of urls, and when those products are crawled i need to store them in database under their id.

problem is i can't understand how to pass id to parse function so that i can store crawled item under their id.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Initialize start urls in [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) and pass `id` in [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta):

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    mapping = [(1, 'my_url1'), (2, 'my_url2')]

    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        for id, url in self.mapping:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'id': id})

    def parse_page(self, response):
        id = response.meta['id']
```

Comment: Has the syntax changed? Why is self.mapping being called as a function when it appears to be a list?